# Restaurant Queue Simulation marking error in function

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue, simulation

I'm creating a restaurant simulation for my data structures class using a queue, and have a good idea for how to do this, but my program keeps throwing an error and marking my function that increments the "wait time" variable of all "customers" in the queue.

Sometimes my program will run all the way through and generate a value for the average wait time, and other times it will break after the first or second customer is generated. I thought that my conditionals that I made my `incrementWaitTime` function with would prevent it from reading from a NULL memory location, but apparently they haven't. Could someone glance over my source code and help me figure out what's broken?

Edit: Here's the exact error that my program is throwing:

> "Unhandled exception at 0x010419aa in Homework 2 Restaurant Queue.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000018."

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class Customer{
public:
    int WaitTime, ServiceTime, OrderCounter, ServiceCounter, OrderTime, test;
    Customer *next;

    Customer(){
        test = 0;
        OrderCounter = 0;
        WaitTime = 0;
        ServiceTime = 0;
        OrderTime = 0;
        next = NULL;
    }
};

class Queue{
public:
    Customer *top, *bottom;
    int totalWaitTime, totalCustomers; 
    Queue(){
        bottom = NULL;
        top = NULL;
        totalWaitTime = 0;
        totalCustomers = 0;
    }

void incrementWaitTime(){
    Customer *temp;
    temp = top;
    if(top == NULL){
        return;
    }
    else{
        if(temp->next == bottom){
            temp->WaitTime++;
        }
        else{
            while(temp->next != bottom){
            temp->WaitTime = temp->WaitTime + 1;
            temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
    }
}

void displayContents(){
    Customer *temp;
    temp = top;
    while(temp!= NULL){
        cout << temp->test << "---->"; 
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void newCustomer(int x){
    Customer *temp = new Customer;
    temp->OrderTime = x;
    if(top == NULL){ //No customers in line
        top = bottom = temp;
        totalCustomers++;
        cout << "There is a new customer." << endl;
    }
    else{
        temp->next = top;
        top = temp;
        totalCustomers++;
        cout << "There is a new customer." << endl;
    }
}

void removeCustomer(){
    Customer *chase, *follow;
    chase = follow = top;
    if(top == NULL){
        //No customers in queue.
        cout << "No customers are in line.. there's nothing to remove." << endl;
        return;
    }
    else{
        if(top->next == NULL){
            //Only one customer
            delete top;
            top = NULL;
            bottom = NULL;
            return;
        }
        while(chase->next != NULL){
            follow = chase;
            chase = chase->next;
        } 
        delete chase;
        bottom = follow;
        follow->next = NULL;
    }
}

void checkStatus(){
    if(top == NULL){
        bottom = NULL;
        return;
    }
    else if(bottom->OrderCounter != bottom->OrderTime){
        bottom->OrderCounter++;
        bottom->WaitTime++;
    }
    else{
        totalWaitTime = totalWaitTime + bottom->WaitTime;
        removeCustomer();
    }
}
};



int main(){
Queue Restaurant;
int Clock = 1, totalCustomers = 0;
float probArrival = 0;
srand(time(NULL)); //seeds random number generator
int number, orderTime, TotalWaitTime, TotalServiceTime;

while(Clock < 1140){
    while(Clock < 120){
        number = rand();
        number = number%10+1; //Generates a number between 1 and 10
        if(number >=1 && number <= 3){
            orderTime = rand();
            orderTime = orderTime%6 + 1; //Creates orderTime between 1 and 6
            Restaurant.newCustomer(orderTime);
            cout << "The time is: " << Clock << " minutes." << endl;
            Clock++;
        }
        else{
            Restaurant.checkStatus();
            Restaurant.incrementWaitTime();
            cout << "The time is: " << Clock << " minutes." << endl;
            Clock++;
        }
    }
    Clock = 1140;
}
cout << "There were " << Restaurant.totalCustomers << " customers. " << endl;
cout << "Average wait time was: " << Restaurant.totalWaitTime / Restaurant.totalCustomers << " minutes per customer." << endl;


system("pause");
return 1;
}
```

Comment: Ideally customer should not know which is the next customer. This is tying your object to a particular data structure. What if you customer one day enters two queues at the same time? And for a generic data structure, incrementing the wait time is a use of the queue, not an intrinsic property of a queue. What if you wanted a queue for food orders? Would you write a new queue with duplicated logic?

Comment: It's generally a good idea to include the exact text of the error message...don't make us guess!   You should run the program under a debugger, which will allow you to inspect the variable values when it crashes, or step through it to see if it's doing what you expect it to do.

Comment: Consider the case when you have exactly one customer in queue, so that `top == bottom` and `top->next == NULL`. What happens in your `incrementWaitTime()`?

Comment: @NeilKirk I'm not sure I understand what you're saying in regards to incrementing the wait time.. Are you saying I should just make Total Wait Time a variable in the main function instead of making it a property of the queue?

Comment: `incrementWaitTime` should not be a function inside `Queue`. Instead it should be a function external to Queue, which takes a Queue instance, and iterates along it doing whatever needs to be done.

Comment: @T.C. it would be undefined behavior? Top != NULL, and temp->next != bottom, so it increments temp's WaitTime by 1, and then sets temp = a memory location that doesn't contain anything?

Comment: @ColinButler and your while loop repeats. What happens next?

Comment: @T.C. and then it attempts to read temp->WaitTime of a non existing memory location and throws that access violation error. Thanks! Stressed programmer-student working under a hard deadline.. I appreciate the help.